# Universal scale bar for paneled levelplots

Tags: r, lattice

I would like to have multiple heatmaps/levelplots in a single plot, with a universal scale bar. I have the plots arranged, and I think I'm close to the answer, but I want to make sure I don't mess the scale up.

```
#Fake data
library(gridExtra)
fill = rnorm(100,4)
matA = matrix(fill, ncol=10)
matB = matrix(fill * 2, ncol=10)

# Plotting
a=levelplot(matA, colorkey=FALSE)
b=levelplot(matB, colorkey=list(col=rainbow(1000), at=seq(0,6, length.out=1000)))

grid.arrange(a,b,ncol=2)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `grid.arrange`, you may rearrange your data to be able to use the `formula` method of `x` in `levelplot`. This allows you to easily create a plot with different panels based on a grouping variable `g`, with a common scale. Here `g` ('L1') corresponds to the different matrices.

```
library(reshape2)
library(lattice)

# put your matrices in a list an melt them to one data frame.
l <- list(matA, matB)
df <- melt(l)

# plot
levelplot(value ~ Var1 * Var2 | L1, data = df,
          col.regions = rainbow(100))
```

[image]